# I would like to send verification email to microsoft office student email via firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am making an app for my school. To sign up my app they have to use student email. Then my app is going to send verification email to student email.

**Only way to check the email sent to student email is using microsoft outlook with student account. And somehow microsoft outlook block the verification email. Email is never delivered to student account.**

**Is there any ways to solve this problem? I don't think Delist works to me because it is super small project... Thanks for reading!**

I was googling about 2 hours. But still I couldn't find helpful information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.